# How to use the module "re " to display the content of text file on text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing the Final Year Project about the GUI of Aircrack-ng. In my GUI design, the result of cracking password will be write into the text file. And that i write the code to read the text file and display the content what i need . Now i can display some information(Target AP,ESSID ,KEY) on the testbox. I also need to display the ASCII password. I have to refer the document about re  (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and try it but not successful. I hope someone can teach me how to do.Thank you.

This is the text file about the result of cracking password

https://drive.google.com/open?id=192IQr5Y2VUjIZBdUrAlD5uyQQ8YSOUDw

This is the function and GUI Design about display the detail for wep password

```
# Use pandas to filter the results and display to textbox
       def wepresult():
               result = re.search(r"\[([^[]+[^(])\]", wepcrackresult_text.get("1.0", 'end-1c'))
               if result:
                   wepcrackresult_text.delete(0.0, END)
                   wepcrackresult_text.insert(INSERT, "Target ESSID: " + self.controller.shared_data[
                       "ESSID"].get() + "\nTarget MAC address: " + self.controller.shared_data[
                                                  "BSSID"].get() + "\nKEY:" + result.group(1))
```

## GUI Design

```
wepcrackresult_button = tk.Button(self, text='4.Check', font='Verdana 14',command = wepresult)
wepcrackresult_button.place(x=2, y=630)
```

Comment: If the code is multiline, you should format it using multiline code formatting, with `Ctrl+K` or `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.

Comment: Why is your text file included as an image? Now we are unable to test any possible solutions. (Automatic -1; [edit] to retrieve.)

Comment: I have been upload the file and you can test it .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simplest code I can think of:

```
import tkinter as tk


def display_file(file_path):
    txt.delete('1.0', 'end')
    with open(file_path) as f:
        file_content_as_string = f.read()
    # regex filterings can be made in filte_content_as_string
    txt.insert('1.0', file_content_as_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    txt = tk.Text(root)

    # replace __file__ with path
    display_file(__file__)

    txt.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i want to know how to use the module "re". As i know "^" is about to match the start of the string